# The infinite sum of the reciprocal of a strictly increasing sequence is irrational if we place a limiting condition on the se quence itself

Tags: calculus

Let $(x_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence. Further suppose

$$ \lim (x_n)^{1/2^n} = \infty $$

Then, $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{x_n} $ is $\mathbf{irrational} $.

Do you think it is true?

Perhaps it would also work if we replace the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ with $\frac{1}{N^n} $ where $N$ is a natural number.

P.S: all the $x_n's$ are natural numbers.

Comment: I think the title could be made more descriptive of the actual question.

Comment: izœc's suggestion still applies...

Comment: I have edited the title. You guys happy? Also, I dont understand the downvote.

Comment: I have placed another condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$
\alpha_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x_k}.
$$

Your condition can be written as
$$
  \frac{\log x_k}{2^k} \to +\infty
$$
i.e. $x_k \ge c 2^{(2^k)}$ for $k$ large enough.
This means $|\alpha_n - \alpha| \le c\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2^k}}$ hence $\alpha$ satisfies [Liouville condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) so it is trascendental.

See also [here](http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/journal/pdf/jms080206.pdf).

Comment: Gracias! :) ...

Comment: Are you a professor? or a student? (If you dont mind me asking)